# Laravel Installation: Dependencies not installed

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm following the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#installing-laravel) and trying to install a fresh installation of Laravel with the following command:

`laravel new pathology-lab`

When I run this command I get the following error:

[image]

There is no vendor directory created. I had to run `composer install` to install laravel dependencies.

But the Laravel docs says that with `laravel new` command the dependent packages are automatically installed:

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong? or Is there any problem with my Composer/Laravel Installer?

I'm able to install Laravel without any errors through Composer:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Comment: I guess `laravel new` is just buggy, it doesn't work for me too and I always use composer to create new Laravel projects.

Comment: Did you run `composer global require "laravel/installer"` ?

Comment: yes. I've run that command. The 'laravel new' command has worked properly in the past. Last time I ran that command was a month back and it worked perfectly.

Comment: You can also create the project using composer `composer create-project laravel/laravel myProjectName`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report, please report your bug in the official Laravel issue trackers.

Comment: ok. looks like its a bug, but I did not know this before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no, you're not doing anything wrong. You're correct about the intended function of `laravel new blog` and the auto-installation of dependencies. I would recommend that you submit this as a bug report or fix the issue and submit a pull request.

This is also a very dated question, and for new people coming across it from Google, it's very unlikely that this bug still exists, and updating to the latest version of laravel should resolve it.